# Docker compose service keeps using the wrong Dockerfile

Tags: .net, docker, docker-compose

I have a .NET project with the following folder structure (stripped down for brevity's sake)

```
myproject/
├─ docker/
│  ├─ sql/
│  │  ├─ docker-compose.yaml/
│  │  ├─ Dockerfile/
├─ src/
├─ tests/
│  ├─ integrationtests/
│  │  ├─ docker-compose.yaml/
│  │  ├─ Dockerfile/
```

The following docker-compose file is defined in the `integrationtests` folder:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  my-db:
    container_name: my-db
    build:
      context: ../../docker/sql
      dockerfile: ${PWD:-.}/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    
  integration-tests:
    depends_on:
      - my-db
    build: ./
    volumes:
      - ../../:/app
    working_dir: /app
    environment:
      - ConnectionString__MySqlServerDb=Data Source=my-db;User ID=sa;Password=$str0ngP@ss2;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False
    command: "dotnet test pathToIntegrationTestProj"
```

Dockerfile inside integrationtests:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0

ENV REPORTGENERATOR_VERSION 4.8.12

RUN dotnet tool install dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool \
    --tool-path /tools \
    --version $REPORTGENERATOR_VERSION
```

Dockerfile inside `./docker/sql`:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
## Run some script to seed database
```

Up until yesterday, if I ran `docker-compose up integration-tests`, it would spin up `my-db` and run the integration tests. But for some reason the `my-db` service is no longer able to use the `docker/sql/Dockerfile` anymore.

If I run `docker-compose up my-db`, in the logs I can see that it's trying to use the Dockerfile inside `integrationtest` folder instead, which doesn't make any sense to me. I am clearly setting the build context and dockerfile path in `my-db`'s definition.

Could someone shed some light on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You already define the `context` in the `build` key so you don't need the `${PWD:-.}` in the `dockerfile` directive. The `dockerfile` directive is only there in case you haven't named your Dockerfile `Dockerfile`.

```
services:
  my-db:
    container_name: my-db
    build:
      context: ../../docker/sql
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
```

Alternatively, you can simplify the whole thing by just doing as seen below.

```
services:
  my-db:
    container_name: my-db
    build: ../../docker/sql
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
```

Comment: This did not fix the issue. I can still see it running the wrong Dockerfile if I only spin up `my-db`

Comment: Hmm ok I don't know what else to try other than deleting the `my-db` image and then just running `docker-compose up` from the `integrationtests` folder.